# Display Browser Image within Canvas in React

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I am trying to simply load a local image and draw it to the browser within a canvas element within a react functional component but am struggling:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Canvas({ width, height }) {

    const myCanvas = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const context = myCanvas.current.getContext('2d');
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = '/home/ben/consensys/eth-og/src/static/preview.jpg';
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    })

    return (
        <canvas
            ref={myCanvas}
            width={width}
            height={height}
        />
    )
}
```

Then in App.js:

```
import Canvas from './Canvas';

function App() {

  return (
    <Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>
      <div className="App">
        <Canvas height={500} width={500} />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My browser is displaying the canvas element, but there is no image on it, just an empty placeholder. Any ideas?

Comment: [Your code does work](https://jsfiddle.net/yecdgs06/). Are you sure the path to your image is correct? (Note in the example I gave the `useEffect` an empty dependency array, and used the width and height props in Canvas.

Comment: Yes I think the path name is the issue. The picture in in the directory one level above called 'static'. For some reason '../static/preview.jpg' does not work for the image.src. Should I be putting the image in the public folder or somthing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base on shared code, the issue is on image load. You are trying to draw the image before it loaded, that's why the canvas displays an empty block...

You can resolve this issue by using `image.onload`, for example:

```
  const myCanvas = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const context = myCanvas.current.getContext("2d");
    const image = new Image();
    image.src =
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Picture_icon_BLACK.svg/1200px-Picture_icon_BLACK.svg.png";
    image.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 500);
    };
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={myCanvas} width={500} height={500} />;
```

And this is [demo url](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sun-jyth0?file=/src/App.js:99-528) (copied from your code)