# How to render png to a HTML canvas in React?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, next.js

Got this error:

```
'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

when I add following 3 lines to my`draw` method:

```js
let newImage = new Image()
        newImage.src = 'https://fjolt.com/images/misc/202203281.png'
        ctx.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, 250, 208)
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const Canvas = (props) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null)

    const draw = (ctx) => {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(50, 100, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        ctx.fill()
        let newImage = new Image() // <--- HERE
        newImage.src = 'https://fjolt.com/images/misc/202203281.png'
        ctx.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, 250, 208)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

        //Our draw come here
        draw(context)
        canvas.toBlob(
            (b) => {
                console.log(b)
            },
            'image/jpeg',
            0.95
        )
    }, [draw])

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props} />
}

export default Canvas
```

Strange, bacause I allowed images to use from that domain:

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: [
            'https://fjolt.com',
        ],
        deviceSizes: [320, 375, 450, 540, 640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920],
    },
```

I tried this approach also, ipired from here: [Display Browser Image within Canvas in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891817/display-browser-image-within-canvas-in-react)

```
let newImage = new Image()
        newImage.src = 'https://fjolt.com/images/misc/202203281.png'
        newImage.onload = () => {
            ctx.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, 500, 500)
        }
```

Comment: You may try adding `newImage.crossorigin="anonymous"`

Comment: I see, it raise now an other one :) `Access to image at 'https://fjolt.com/images/misc/202203281.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: That's something that can only be fixed on the server end. They have to allow images to your domain by adding the CORS header.

Comment: Ok, I use now my own bucket, and CORS settings are set. Would you check it I need extra adjustment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72760767/access-to-image-at-xxx-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy